# Remove File on SFTP using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sftp

I'm struggling with the below code. Want to delete a file that is on SFTP.  Unable to understand how to accomplish this -

```
$UserName = 'test'
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String '3ea5e@9dkdadfsfwC' -AsPlainText -Force 
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePassword

$Session = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName 'sftp.test.com' -Credential $Cred

$result = Remove-Item  -LiteralPath "\\?sftp://test@sftp.test.com/export/home/dmsmaster/stms/PF/Working_Titles_Primary.csv" -Force
```

Comment: I haven't used this module before, but Remove-Item is the standard command for removing a LOCAL file. I think you wan to use the Remove-SFTPItem command from the module you are using.

Comment: `New-SFTPSession` is not an internal Powershell command, but one that is either specific to a module that you have installed or written yourself. You should specify which module you're using that contains this command. If you're not sure, you can run `Get-Command New-SFTPSession` and the `Source` and `Version` columns will tell you.

Comment: @BaconBits Source is Posh-SSH

Answer (score 0):

Used the following code to make it work -

```
$result = Remove-SFTPItem -path  "/export/home/dmsmaster/stms/PF/Working_Titles_Primary.csv" -SFTPSession $Session -Force
```